# close event not working?

Tags: qt, qtgui

Ok, so why is this code not working??

```
void Jarvis::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *e)
{
    if (m_doQuit) {
        e->accept();
    } else {
        e->ignore();
        hide();
    }
}
```

m_doQuit is true, I checked that.

For now I am using

```
void Jarvis::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *e)
{
    if (m_doQuit) {
        QApplication::quit();
        e->accept();
    } else {
        e->ignore();
        hide();
    }
}
```

which does work, but IMHO should work even the first one. Why it does not work?

By "doest not work" I mean that application is not closed :/ It just keeps running.

Comment: can you specify what do you mean by "not working" or "does work"?

Comment: I modified my question

Comment: Why do you think that application should close in 1st case?

Comment: Well.. I can abort close event in closeEvent method right? And I thought that close event is emitted when application is closing.. + if I remove my method, it works as expected (application terminates)

Comment: maybe you have not comment `QApplication::setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(false);`.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that *Jarvis* inherits QWidget.

Then you shoud pass the event to the QWidget class like this:

```
void Jarvis::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *e)
{
    if (m_doQuit) {
        QWidget::closeEvent(e);
    } else {
        e->ignore();
        hide();
    }
}
```

Simply accepting the event will do nothing. Maybe you could accept the event in the second case, since you *are* somehow reacting to it. Even though you don't close... but that's for a reason.

Comment: Jarvis inherits QMainWindow.. So I tried putting QMainWindow::closeEvent(e) there, but did not help..